# Copy file from remote machine when it changes

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp, rsync

I'm using this script to detect when a file changes in a remote machine and copy it when it does:

```sh
interval=5
target_file=/home/sergioro/file
last_modified=0
while :; do
    last_modified_new=$(ssh jh 2>/dev/null stat -c %Y $target_file)
    if [ $last_modified_new -gt $last_modified ]; then
        last_modified=$last_modified_new
        rsync -az jh:$target_file log/ 2>/dev/null
    fi
    sleep $interval
done &
```

This works but I would prefer to perform a persistent `ssh` connection instead of making multiple `ssh` calls. Is there a tool or SSH option to keep the `ssh` connection open and copy the file if changes? Thanks.

Comment: Consider taking a look on this question and answer: https://superuser.com/questions/254530/rsync-only-changed-files/254531#254531

Comment: This might help: [Mount remote directory using SSH](https://askubuntu.com/q/412477/336375)

Comment: have a look at [lsyncd](https://serverfault.com/a/485808/550521) . it uses inotify to check whether file changed and makes a copy at once change is detected.